# Microsoft Access 2010 is not saving data in datetime Format

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an  Access table with a datetime field.

On my form I have datetime picker and set the format properties to General which should, I believe input the date and time. In my case it is only showing the date in the control and the database.

Can someone explain how to get a datetime in Access?

Comment: What datetime picker? Access has an inbuilt date picker, which only picks a date. To add time, you have to enter that.

Comment: thanks @Andre Kind of new to Access why would they have a general format option that shows date and time but no way to use a function like date.Now().  I was hoping to have a field that would log the date and time when a user clicked a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are populating the field using the date picker, this will only populate a date value for the selected date, with no time component.

If you wish to enter a date with a time component, you will either need to type the date & time manually into the control, or populate the value of the control automatically using the `Now()` function.

Since you wish to record the date & time that a user has clicked a button, simply populate the field value using the `Now()` function as part of the event handler for the `OnClick` event of the button control, e.g.:

```vb
Private Sub YourButton_Click()
    YourDateControl.Value = Now()
    ' ... Do other stuff ...
End Sub
```